# EdgeRouter Route Incoming Traffic to another Public Network/Server

Tags: tunnel, ip-forwarding, gre

I am curious if this is possible in theory? At my colo datacenter, I have a lot of public IP addresses (/21) on a 1GB circuit using an Edge Router 6P (not using BGP). I want to temporarily rent a server in another data center until I can get more space at my current one. I'd like to be able to forward a few IPs to another Server that also has public IPs.

For example:
199.XXX.XXX.50-51 -> 88.XXX.XXX.60-61

Is this just a simple static route or do I need to do something more complex like a GRE-Tunnel?

Basically, I want the rented server at the other location to respond to my 199.XXX.XXX.50-51 network.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't feasible outside of handling your own BGP (and having 2 AS, one for each PoP) or having your colo do it for you somehow (via E.G., MPLS).